# Is it ever okay to not use an ELSE statement if you have a return or throw inside the IF statement?

Tags: algorithm, coding-style, logic, control-structure

I often write code such as the following

```
bool myFunct (...)
{
     if (something)
     {
          return false; 
     }         

     // .... more code ....

}
```

The alternative is

```
bool myFunct (...)
{
     if (something)
     {
          return false; 
     }         
     else
     {
          // .... more code ....
     }

}
```

Of course, that `else` block is unnecessary, because the early `return` means that reaching the `else` statement in the first place is the equivalent of being inside it. Then there's the fact that, to make the compiler happy, I often have to change the structure of the 2nd implementation to

```
bool myFunct (...)
{
     bool retval = true;
     if (something)
     {
          retval = false; 
     }         
     else
     {
          // .... more code ....
     }
     return retval;    
}
```

which is extra code and looks stupid. My question is, what do the governing authorities and priests say about this type of situation?

Comment: Why do you think that the last one "looks stupid"?

Comment: I think that redundant `else` clauses are definitely an anti-pattern.

Comment: related: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/18454/should-i-return-from-a-function-early-or-use-an-if-statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not only it is OK, it is even **encouraged in [Spartan Programming](https://ssdl-wiki.cs.technion.ac.il/wiki/index.php/Spartan_programming)**. According to Spartan Programming - shorter and simpler code is better, and you achive it (among other ways) by fast terminations and avoiding  `else` statements when possible

Under minimizing use of control:

> (2) Simplifying conditionals with early `return`.
>
> (4) Simplifying logic of iteration with early exits (via 
>   `return`, `continue` and `break` statements).

P.S. [It seems @Jeff Atwood also likes the spartan programming way](http://blog.codinghorror.com/spartan-programming/)

Answer (score 2):

Of course.  You're basically writing a guard condition that will stop you trying to perform unnecessary logic.  It's fine.

Like many things, it's personal preference, but I prefer to see code written like your second example for simple cases, and the third example for more complex cases.  That doesn't mean any are wrong, though.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing technically wrong with having an `else` clause for an `if` clause that does not terminate naturally (e.g., has a `return` or `throw` statement), it's just useless.

Several style guidelines argue against it (and several IDE and analysis tools may produce warnings to support these guidelines), but ultimately, it's just a preference.

Answer (score 0):

The 2nd example looks fine to me because, if the code in the first statement is updated like below, it'll prevent unexpected behavior :

```
bool myFunct (...)
{
     if (something)
     {
          // ... stuff 
          if (something_else) return false; 
     }         
     else
     {
          // .... more code ....
     }

}
```